# Is there an equivalent of python's dir() on dart?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

As the title says, is there an equivalent of python's `dir()` on dart?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Python [dir() function](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/dir.html), is used to find out which names a module defines.

We can use [Mirrors](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_mirrors.html) and write an equivalent function on our own (or at least very similar):

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

List<String> dir([String libraryName]) {
  var lib, symbols = [];

  if (?libraryName) {
    lib = currentMirrorSystem().libraries[libraryName];
  } else {
    lib = currentMirrorSystem().isolate.rootLibrary;
  }

  lib.members.forEach((name, mirror) => symbols.add(name));

  return symbols;
}
```

Now here's an example:

```dart
class Hello {}

bar() => print('yay');

main() {
  var foo = 5;

  print(dir()); // [main, bar, Hello, dir]
}
```

Or specify a library:

```dart
print(dir('dart:mirrors'));
```

> [MirroredError, TypeMirror, ObjectMirror, _LazyLibraryMirror,
>   TypeVariableMirror, MirrorException, ClassMirror, MirrorSystem,
>   _LocalMirrorSystemImpl, _LocalVMObjectMirrorImpl, DeclarationMirror, _LazyTypeMirror, _LocalClosureMirrorImpl, mirrorSystemOf, _LazyFunctionTypeMirror, _filterMap, MirroredCompilationError, _Mirrors, _LocalClassMirrorImpl, _LocalInstanceMirrorImpl, _LocalTypedefMirrorImpl,
>   _LocalFunctionTypeMirrorImpl, reflect, MethodMirror, _LocalVariableMirrorImpl, LibraryMirror, _LocalIsolateMirrorImpl, FunctionTypeMirror, _LocalLibraryMirrorImpl, Mirror,
>   _LocalObjectMirrorImpl, _LocalMirrorImpl, _makeSignatureString, _LocalTypeVariableMirrorImpl, Comment, MirroredUncaughtExceptionError, _LocalParameterMirrorImpl, _LazyTypeVariableMirror, TypedefMirror, VariableMirror, IsolateMirror, currentMirrorSystem, _dartEscape,
>   _LocalMethodMirrorImpl, ClosureMirror, VMReference, ParameterMirror, InstanceMirror, _isSimpleValue, SourceLocation]

This literally tells what has been defined in the particular library (module). Now there can be some differences to Python's function, which also seems to sort the names, but this should give you a head-start.

Comment: Mirrors is not available.